# Javascript and css substracting a pixel

Tags: javascript, css

Basically what I'm trying to loop through this:

```
var x = this.div.offsetLeft;
this.div.style.left = (x+this.pixelx)+"px";
```

where this.pixelx takes values of 1 and -1.

When it has a value of 1, it works smoothly without any issues, but when it has the value of -1 "this.div" moves for around 5 times and then stops moving.

Any ideas on what might be happening? Thanks.

EDIT:

this is the jsFiddle with a sample of the code. You are suppoused to move the ball with the left and right arrows on the keyboard: http://jsfiddle.net/KmrbV/1/

EDIT:

It seems the problem is only happening in my computer. I'm running it on chrome Version 23.0.1271.64, my OS is ubuntu 12.04. 
The keys aren't the issue. As the matter of fact it only happens with -1. if i use -2, it works fine as well.

Comment: Demo please? jsfiddle perhaps?

Comment: A shot in the dark, but is -1 being passed as a string? try: (x+(+this.pixelx))+"px";

Comment: @Brian To me, that's a "side-effect" way of converting and thus is not best practice. Please see my answer for what (I think) is best practice for string-to-number conversion in Javascript.

Comment: Your sample works just fine for me (on Chrome). Maybe it's something with your local keyboard repetition settings?

Comment: @ErikE It's not a side-effect, Brian's code is using the [unary plus operator `+`](http://es5.github.com/#x11.4.6) (not the addition operator `+`), that, by definition, "converts its operand to Number type".

Comment: Browser trying to scroll or select something maybe? When you say the div moves by around 5 pixels, have you tried monitoring what exactly is happening, e.g. by writing messages to the console http://jsfiddle.net/KmrbV/7/. Also if the ball is inside a containing element then offsetLeft won't get its position relative to the page (but that doesn't apply to your demo)